# Python - Regex (Removing Brackets and Commas)

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I'm new to Python and Regex patterns and it's been very frustrating.
I'd be very much appreciated if someone can assist me in finding the correct patten to remove three things (1) ',' (2) '] (3) ['

```
with open(f"/home/pi/students/{biometric_id}.txt") as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    content = str([item.replace('\n', '<br>') for item in content])
    #content = re.sub(r"\([^()]*\)", "", content)
    return render_template("Page-4.html", content=content)
```

> [' ', ' ', ' ', 'Item: Cheese Wrap ', 'Cost: $3.00 ', 'Remaining Balance:
> $12.2 ', '-------------------------- ']

Comment: show more example of sample data

Comment: ['STUDENT DETAILS -
', 'Biometric ID: 653694
', 'RFID: 18985211235
', 'Full Name: James John
', 'Balance: $15.2
', '--------------------------
', '
', '
', 'Item: Cheese Wrap
', 'Cost: $3.00
', 'Remaining Balance: $12.2
', '--------------------------
']

Comment: [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/51Xw7v/1) [CODE](https://regex101.com/r/51Xw7v/1/codegen?language=python)

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realise there was an Regex Expression Builder :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
content = "['STUDENT DETAILS - ', 'Biometric ID: 653694 ', 'RFID: 18985211235 ', 'Full Name: James John ', 'Balance: $15.2 ', '-------------------------- ', ' ', ' ', 'Item: Cheese Wrap ', 'Cost: $3.00 ', 'Remaining Balance: $12.2 ', '-------------------------- '] "
content = re.sub(r"(\',\s?\')|(\'\])|(\[\')", r"", content)
print(content)
```

Output:

```
STUDENT DETAILS - Biometric ID: 653694 RFID: 18985211235 Full Name: James John Balance: $15.2 --------------------------   Item: Cheese Wrap Cost: $3.00 Remaining Balance: $12.2 --------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you have here is a file with list items.

So what you do is to read it in and "evaluate" them as list items:

```
with open(f"/home/pi/students/{biometric_id}.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        data = eval(line)
        for item in data:
            # do something useful with the data
            print(item)
```

If the file contained:

```
['STUDENT DETAILS - ', 'Biometric ID: 653694 ', 'RFID: 18985211235 ', 'Full Name: James John ', 'Balance: $15.2 ', '-------------------------- ', ' ', ' ', 'Item: Cheese Wrap ', 'Cost: $3.00 ', 'Remaining Balance: $12.2 ', '-------------------------- ']
```

The above would print out:

```
STUDENT DETAILS -
Biometric ID: 653694
RFID: 18985211235
Full Name: James John
Balance: $15.2
--------------------------


Item: Cheese Wrap
Cost: $3.00
Remaining Balance: $12.2
--------------------------
```

Comment: you are correct that there are better ways of parsing this list data. however, `eval` really is dangerous. consider `ast.literal_eval` or other parsing routines

Answer (score 0):

When you want to validate your regex I recommend you to use: https://regexr.com/

About your question, try with

```
content = "Hola, (mundo)"
re.sub(r'[,()]', '', content)

>> 'Hola mundo'
```

What do you think?